# How to avoid error when accessing elements in JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got error in this javascript code. Error is `TypeError: checkboxes[d] is undefined`
There is my javascript code. I need to compare same values in this code.

```
 var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox:checked");
        var nbCheckbox = checkboxes.length;
        var deger=document.getElementById('mergeto').value;
        var url=document.URL;
        var temp=new Array();
        var namecheck; 
        var othercheck;
        var sending=0;

        temp=url.split('?');
var url='/cgi-bin/koha/cataloguing/dev_biblio_merge.pl?mergeto='+deger+'&biblionumber='+checkboxes[0].value;
     if (nbCheckbox){
        for (var j=0;j<nbCheckbox;j++){
                namecheck=checkboxes[j].name;
        for (var d=j;d<=nbCheckbox;d++){
                othercheck=checkboxes[d].name;
        for (var i=1;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
         url+='&biblionumber=' + checkboxes[i].value;
        }}} 
        url+='&'+temp[1];
        window.location=url;
        }
        window.location=url;
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `=` from the condition of `for..d` loop, you're dealing with zero-based indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning with this code:

```
    for (var d=j;d<=nbCheckbox;d++){
            othercheck=checkboxes[d].name;
```

You need to write:

```
    for (var d=j;d<nbCheckbox;d++){
            othercheck=checkboxes[d].name;
```

because *checkboxes[nbCheckbox]* isn't defined

Comment: The OBOE strikes again!